# While testing Rails controller, I want to view the HTML response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

In a rails controller test (ActionController::TestCase), I want to print the rendered HTML on the console so that I can inspect it.  Using pry, I detected an instance variable in the scope of my test block called 'html_document' of class HTML::Document, but it is huge and I cannot find any method (out of what must be several hundred!) that will render it's payload to plain HTML that I can view in my console in order to inspect it.  Isn't there a simple way to get at the response payload as plain text (albeit in its own markup)?

Comment: look at the `response` variable

Comment: I did, but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In the controller test:

```
test "/account with session routes user to view own account page" do
  user = create :user
  sign_in :user, user
  get :view_account
  assert_select "span.id" do |span|
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

In pry

```
[33] pry(#<UsersControllerTest>)> span[0].to_s
=> "<span class=\"id\">726133241</span>"
```

Just what I was looking for!